# Why can hackers get in network using tunneling?

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, vpn, tunneling

I can't hack but I like to read about it. From my readings (securityfocus, exploit-db, owasp, etc...) it appears that hackers can actually get in a network using tunneling ; I'm not from a network background but tunnelling is mostly for VPN right ? (Yes !)

What I mean is writen here [at offensive security OSCP](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/) on the right (bullet point number 6)

So that would mean that even a firewall can't block them. How is that possible ? Is that the reason why when they find a new exploit on a software they can just get in the network and from there have fun exploiting the zero day ?

Comment: If you say you can't hack, you most certainly can't. But ginger kiddies with kits like core impact can hack? Feh... to tunnel you need only a single connection, sometimes masquerading as another type of traffic. DNS and HTTP POST/GET are adequate. Many packetfilters will even pass 53/tcp, because it's used for zone transfers, so not only 53/udp is allowed, giving you TCP error correction. Pick up a guide to TCP/IP in python, and you can compress and exfiltrate data reliably tomorrow.

Comment: As well as being too broad, this appears to be a Re-asking of your previous question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/146385/485 please read our [about] and [ask] pages

Comment: @RoryAlsop That is true. I was into that theme few days ago...I did not realized I was repeatting myself. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tunnelling to bypass firewall filtering means that an attacker uses a "trusted" protocol in order to exfiltrate data from the victim machine.

For example, an attacker can inject exfiltrated data into a lookup DNS requests sent to a fake dns server controlled by him.

Victim machine--->DNS REQUEST--->FIREWALL--->Attacker FAKE DNS Server

You can reach the same goal with different protocols, think about maleware with a gmail account as C&C.

Comment: How a bout the other wary ? That is, does it mean that an attacker can get inside a network using the same thing ? .... embedding a malicious payload in a tunnel to avoid firewall detection ?

Comment: Here we are talking about a post- exploitation technique. That means an attacker has to gain access to the victim machine, for example, exploiting a vulnerability or through orher kinds of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

VPN tunnels are generally set up in two ways:

- Parallel to the firewall or
- Through the firewall

If an attacker has a victim inside a network, but is unable to exfiltrate data as it's being dropped by a packet analyzer (usually on the firewall) then a tunnel is the perfect alternative - it allows you to shuttle data out in an encrypted form, completely bypassing any filters.