# SSL VPN network placement

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Where should I place an SSL VPN appliance like OpenVPN Access Server on my network to enable users to secure remote access to corporate resources?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that most UTM (Unified Threat Management) or NGFW(Next Generation Firewall) may include SSL VPN capability, I'd say it will make sense to add place you appliance behind the firewall... That way, your firewall rules will be enforced before a user can authenticate via your SSL VPN...

SSL VPN will encrypt and create a tunnel for your data...so the firewall won't inspect layer 7 information : see my previous question here -> [Could encryption become a security breach?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146385/could-encryption-become-a-security-breach?noredirect=1#comment275597_146385)

Therefore I believe you want the firewall to do it's job before it allows encrypted traffic of you SSL VPN thrafic (I believe your firewall will know you allpliance right ?)....